# How to run embedded batch file using process.start in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, cmd

I add a batch file. let's say "batch.cmd" in my WPF application. I right click my project and add existing item, add my batch file in the project. I selected my batch file and change Build Action to Embedded Resource. After I build it, I saw this file add in project.

Now I need to start my batch file in my code, I tried `Process.Start("batch.cmd")`, it doesn't work, I did like:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "batch.cmd";
p.Start();
```

It doesn't work either. How can i let my code understand this batch is existing inside my project and somewhere in the \bin. I don;t want to hard code it because the Path will always change.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?. Doesn't start the process?, doesn't get the file?, does the batch fail?. Hepl us a bit to understand your problem.

Comment: Assuming .Net 4.5, try this:  `Process.Start("cmd", "batch.cmd");`

Comment: By doesn't work I mean the application crash, it cannot find "batch.cmd" It doesn't get the file

Comment: What is the batch file doing that you can't do in code?  If you are embedding it, then you are assuming that it will always be the same, so why not just do what it does in code?  I am just curious here, not saying you are wrong in doing this.  It just seems odd.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save file from the resource to disk at run time and than call it from that location (may need to adjust "current directory" if it expects to start from a particular folder).

Links:

- [How to embed and access resources](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292)
- [Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx)  - to get location where to save file (don't forget to delete when done).
- [ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx)

Unverified code below:

```
  var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();

  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetManifestResourceStream("my.cmd")
    .CopyTo(File.OpenWrite(tempFileName);

  Process.Start(tempFileName);
  File.Delete(tempFileName);
```

Comment: @Chelseajcole I've added links - first article contains complete walk through to deal with resources.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this?

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\batch.cmd";
p.Start();
```