# Code or command to use embedded resource in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, embedded-resource

Can somebody provide me a starting point or code to access an embedded resource using C#?

I have successfully embedded a couple of batch files, scripts and CAD drawings which I would like to run the batch and copy the scripts and CAD files to a location specified in the batch file.

I'm struggling to find how to specify what the item is and set the path within the EXE. The below code is what I thought would work, but it failed and the others I found online all related to XML files.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Batchfile.bat";
p.Start();
```

I honestly don't even know if I'm looking at the correct way to do this as this is my first time using either C# or Visual Studio.

Comment: Not sure how relevant this is but I was experiencing a similar issue with `html` and `hta` files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965304/how-to-store-hta-html-file-in-project-resources-and-use-in-program

Comment: Also see this question for details on how to execute `.bat` files - it seems you may have to copy them to disk before running them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141010/how-to-run-embedded-batch-file-using-process-start-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 14):

Open Solution Explorer add files you want to embed. Right click on the files then click on `Properties`. In `Properties` window and change `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`.

[image: Embedding Resource Visual Studio]

After that you should write the embedded resources to file in order to be able to run it.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace YourProject
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        // Other Code...

        private void StartProcessWithFile()
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            //Getting names of all embedded resources
            var allResourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
            //Selecting first one. 
            var resourceName = allResourceNames[0];
            var pathToFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) +
                              resourceName;

            using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(pathToFile))
            {
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }

            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = pathToFile;
            process.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would break up that code sample some so it doesn't appear that your `assembly` declaration (etc) are all a part of the `using` statements at the top of the file. Make it look like real code that anyone can easily read.

Comment: Thanks, I don't really understand the code and how it allows me to select the particular file, but it gives me a start of what to do.

Comment: Play with this line. `var resourceName = allResourceNames[0];`. `allResourceNames` is an array of string containing your embedded resource names.