# asp.net core with resource file (resx)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a project in ASP.Net Core that need to include a image from a resource file (to generate a PDF).

So, I create a new resource file using Visual Studio (Add > New Item > Resources File), named Resource.resx

Using the Managed Resource Editor (default editor of Visual Studio), I included a new image named logo.png.
A new file named `Resource.Designer.cs` was created with a method listed below:

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap logo {
    get {
        object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("logo", resourceCulture);
        return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
    }
}
```

Now, only to test, I created the following code:

```
var logo = Resources.logo;
```

This threw a new exception, with the following content:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred.
 Additional Information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'.`

I tried all from this link too:
https://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/beating-localization-into-submission-on-asp-net-5

but the results are the same.

If I make this code on a console application, everything works correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found another approach that worked good for my problem.

http://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-embedded-resource/

Just need to create a folder on project (Resources in my case), and then, in project.json, I included the following code:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "embed": ["Resources/**/*"]
}
```

and then, my code:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var logoStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectNamespace.Resources.logo.png");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using .net core 3.1 api, you may-

1. Add `services.AddLocalization();`  in ConfigureServices method (Startup.cs)
2. Add Resource file in the project say Resource.en-US.resx, add TestKey in Name and Hello in Value column for testing purpose.
3. Add a class file in the same hierarchy with name as Resource.cs
4. In controller, add a variable-

   private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

and inject it in constructor-

```
public TestController(IStringLocalizer<Resource> localizer)
        {            
            _localizer = localizer;
        }
```

5. Read the value of resource names as-
   `_localizer["TestKey"]` and you will get Hello (i.e. entered in step#2)
   More details at- [https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/how-to-use-localization-in-an-asp-net-core-web-api.aspx]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (csproj files) and this solution worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39368856/812610

`Open Solution Explorer add files you want to embed. Right click on the files then click on Properties. In Properties window and change Build Action to Embedded Resource.`

The embedded resource's name is "[DefaultNamespace].[Folder].filename". I saved a cert (cert.pfx) to "Resources" folder so for me it's "MyProjectName.Resources.cert.pfx"

And this was added to my `.csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Resources\testcert.pfx" />
  </ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\testcert.pfx" />
  </ItemGroup>
```